# How can I tell a GP model that exports a dbf to NOT add it to the 'List by Source' window?

Tags: geoprocessing, modelbuilder

I have a GP Model that simply exports a selected points lat and long to a DBF.  I would like to make it so it does not add the table to the list by source window as it hangs for an annoying amount of time and I do not need to use the exported table in the map anyway.[image: Picture of model in question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In arcmap 10, you could experiment with Geoprocessing Menu | Geoprocessing Options then toggle off Add results of geoprocessing operations to display.  You could export your model to a Python script and simply run it.